# Starting a debugging session in Silverlight takes a very long time

Tags: silverlight, performance, caching, debugging, symbols

In my SL4 LOB app, I’ve probably hit F5 1000x or more with no problems. Suddenly, now hitting F5 can take up to 90 seconds before the app’s  Startup event is raised.

I’ve tried clearing the IE browsers cache, no help there.

I created a new Navigation app with no code whatsoever, hit F5, started up immediately, great.  I then began adding the same assembly references from my SL4 LOB app to the newly created navigation app. After each reference added, I would hit F5 to ensure the app is able to startup immediately; so far so good.

Alas, I finally came to the System.Windows.Controls.Data.Toolkit.dll that caused the same behavior with my original SL4 LOB app. I removed the reference from the navigation app, and again, it would start up immediately.  It’s only 33kb, so I can’t argue that I’m having problems with my symbol cache.

Has anyone else seen this strange behavior? Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The small size of your app will not really matter for how quickly your debugging sessions starts up. The slowdown will be caused by a large number of dependencies in your application.

You did remove a single reference which improved things tremendously and chances are that this single DLL is probably dependent on dozens of other libraries. If you check the process with a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) you can see exactly which libraries get loaded at runtime.

These extraneous dependencies are fairly common. The project wizards you use in Visual Studio will almost always add dependencies to items which your final application will not use. For example, the XML reference is always part of your default project but an does not always need to use XML. It's good practice to go through and remove these unnecessary dependencies after you initially create your project. You can always go back and re-reference them in the future if you need to.